# Padding multiple character with space - python

Tags: python, regex, perl, tokenize, substitution

In `perl`, I can do the following with will pad my punctuation symbols with spaces:

```
s/([،;؛¿!"\])}»›”؟%٪°±©®।॥…])/ $1 /g;`
```

In `Python`, I've tried this:

```
>>> p = u'،;؛¿!"\])}»›”؟%٪°±©®।॥…'
>>> text = u"this, is a sentence with weird» symbols… appearing everywhere¿"
>>> for i in p:
...     text = text.replace(i, ' '+i+' ')
... 
>>> text
u'this, is a sentence with weird \xbb  symbols \u2026  appearing everywhere \xbf '
>>> print text
this, is a sentence with weird »  symbols …  appearing everywhere ¿
```

But is there a way to use some sort of a placeholder symbol, e.g. `$1` in `perl` where I can do the same in `python` with 1 regex?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: @kayess, in this case, it's almost the same question; i think asking another question would result in duplicates. Especially when `\p{Open_Punctuation}` is some what similar to `u""""'<(["""`

Comment: By popular demand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040905/what-is-the-equivalence-of-perluniprops-in-python =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python version of `$1` is `\1`, but you should use regex substitution instead of simple string replace:

```
import re

p = ur'([،;؛¿!"\])}»›”؟%٪°±©®।॥…])'
text = u"this, is a sentence with weird» symbols… appearing everywhere¿"

print re.sub(p, ur' \1 ', text)
```

Outputs:

```
this , is a sentence with weird »  symbols …  appearing everywhere ¿
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub), with `\1` as a placeholder.

```
>>> p = u'،;؛¿!"\])}»›”؟%٪°±©®।॥…'
>>> text = u"this, is a sentence with weird» symbols… appearing everywhere¿"
>>> text = re.sub(u'([{}])'.format(p), r' \1 ', text)
>>> print text
this, is a sentence with weird »  symbols …  appearing everywhere ¿
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `format` function, and insert a `unicode` string:

```
p = u'،;؛¿!"\])}»›”؟%٪°±©®।॥…'
text = u"this, is a sentence with weird» symbols… appearing everywhere¿"
for i in p:
    text = text.replace(i, u' {} '.format(i))

print(text)
```

**Output**

```
this, is a sentence with weird »  symbols …  appearing everywhere ¿
```

Comment: The OP wants to get rid of the `for` loop. Your answer is not semantically different than the original except that yours run a little faster.