# What is the equivalence of perluniprops in python?

Tags: python, regex, perl, unicode

In `perl`, there's the `perluniprops` index of Unicode 7, http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html where I can do the following to pad opening and closing punctuations:

```
s/(\p{Open_Punctuation})/ $1 /g;
s/(\p{Close_Punctuation})/ $1 /g;
```

**What is the full list of opening/closing punctuations that gets padded when using the perl? And what is the equivalence in `python`?**

Related question: [Padding multiple character with space - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037626/padding-multiple-character-with-space-python) [Padding multiple character with space - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037626/padding-multiple-character-with-space-python); this question was asked separatedly by answerer's vote that it should be separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to determine what's the corresponding closing punctuation for a given open punctuation? Unicode does not define this. In fact, there's not even a 1:1 relationship.

```
$ unichars '\p{Open_Punctuation}' | wc -l
75

$ unichars '\p{Close_Punctuation}' | wc -l
73
```

However, It should be relatively easy for you to build your own mapping.

```
$ unichars '\p{Open_Punctuation}' | cat
 (  U+0028 LEFT PARENTHESIS
 [  U+005B LEFT SQUARE BRACKET
 {  U+007B LEFT CURLY BRACKET
 ༺  U+0F3A TIBETAN MARK GUG RTAGS GYON
 ༼  U+0F3C TIBETAN MARK ANG KHANG GYON
 ᚛  U+169B OGHAM FEATHER MARK
 ‚  U+201A SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
 „  U+201E DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
 ⁅  U+2045 LEFT SQUARE BRACKET WITH QUILL
 ⁽  U+207D SUPERSCRIPT LEFT PARENTHESIS
 ₍  U+208D SUBSCRIPT LEFT PARENTHESIS
 ⌈  U+2308 LEFT CEILING
 ⌊  U+230A LEFT FLOOR
 〈 U+2329 LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET
 ❨  U+2768 MEDIUM LEFT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT
 ❪  U+276A MEDIUM FLATTENED LEFT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT
 ❬  U+276C MEDIUM LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT
 ❮  U+276E HEAVY LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
 ❰  U+2770 HEAVY LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT
 ❲  U+2772 LIGHT LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ORNAMENT
 ❴  U+2774 MEDIUM LEFT CURLY BRACKET ORNAMENT
 ⟅  U+27C5 LEFT S-SHAPED BAG DELIMITER
 ⟦  U+27E6 MATHEMATICAL LEFT WHITE SQUARE BRACKET
 ⟨  U+27E8 MATHEMATICAL LEFT ANGLE BRACKET
 ⟪  U+27EA MATHEMATICAL LEFT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET
 ⟬  U+27EC MATHEMATICAL LEFT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
 ⟮  U+27EE MATHEMATICAL LEFT FLATTENED PARENTHESIS
 ⦃  U+2983 LEFT WHITE CURLY BRACKET
 ⦅  U+2985 LEFT WHITE PARENTHESIS
 ⦇  U+2987 Z NOTATION LEFT IMAGE BRACKET
 ⦉  U+2989 Z NOTATION LEFT BINDING BRACKET
 ⦋  U+298B LEFT SQUARE BRACKET WITH UNDERBAR
 ⦍  U+298D LEFT SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN TOP CORNER
 ⦏  U+298F LEFT SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN BOTTOM CORNER
 ⦑  U+2991 LEFT ANGLE BRACKET WITH DOT
 ⦓  U+2993 LEFT ARC LESS-THAN BRACKET
 ⦕  U+2995 DOUBLE LEFT ARC GREATER-THAN BRACKET
 ⦗  U+2997 LEFT BLACK TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
 ⧘  U+29D8 LEFT WIGGLY FENCE
 ⧚  U+29DA LEFT DOUBLE WIGGLY FENCE
 ⧼  U+29FC LEFT-POINTING CURVED ANGLE BRACKET
 ⸢  U+2E22 TOP LEFT HALF BRACKET
 ⸤  U+2E24 BOTTOM LEFT HALF BRACKET
 ⸦  U+2E26 LEFT SIDEWAYS U BRACKET
 ⸨  U+2E28 LEFT DOUBLE PARENTHESIS
 ⹂  U+2E42 DOUBLE LOW-REVERSED-9 QUOTATION MARK
 〈 U+3008 LEFT ANGLE BRACKET
 《 U+300A LEFT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET
 「 U+300C LEFT CORNER BRACKET
 『 U+300E LEFT WHITE CORNER BRACKET
 【 U+3010 LEFT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET
 〔 U+3014 LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
 〖 U+3016 LEFT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET
 〘 U+3018 LEFT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
 〚 U+301A LEFT WHITE SQUARE BRACKET
 〝 U+301D REVERSED DOUBLE PRIME QUOTATION MARK
 ﴿  U+FD3F ORNATE RIGHT PARENTHESIS
 ︗ U+FE17 PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET
 ︵ U+FE35 PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT PARENTHESIS
 ︷ U+FE37 PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT CURLY BRACKET
 ︹ U+FE39 PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
 ︻ U+FE3B PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET
 ︽ U+FE3D PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET
 ︿ U+FE3F PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT ANGLE BRACKET
 ﹁ U+FE41 PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT CORNER BRACKET
 ﹃ U+FE43 PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT WHITE CORNER BRACKET
 ﹇ U+FE47 PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT SQUARE BRACKET
 ﹙ U+FE59 SMALL LEFT PARENTHESIS
 ﹛ U+FE5B SMALL LEFT CURLY BRACKET
 ﹝ U+FE5D SMALL LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
 （ U+FF08 FULLWIDTH LEFT PARENTHESIS
 ［ U+FF3B FULLWIDTH LEFT SQUARE BRACKET
 ｛ U+FF5B FULLWIDTH LEFT CURLY BRACKET
 ｟ U+FF5F FULLWIDTH LEFT WHITE PARENTHESIS
 ｢  U+FF62 HALFWIDTH LEFT CORNER BRACKET
```

```
$ unichars '\p{Close_Punctuation}' | cat
 )  U+0029 RIGHT PARENTHESIS
 ]  U+005D RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET
 }  U+007D RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
 ༻  U+0F3B TIBETAN MARK GUG RTAGS GYAS
 ༽  U+0F3D TIBETAN MARK ANG KHANG GYAS
 ᚜  U+169C OGHAM REVERSED FEATHER MARK
 ⁆  U+2046 RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET WITH QUILL
 ⁾  U+207E SUPERSCRIPT RIGHT PARENTHESIS
 ₎  U+208E SUBSCRIPT RIGHT PARENTHESIS
 ⌉  U+2309 RIGHT CEILING
 ⌋  U+230B RIGHT FLOOR
 〉 U+232A RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET
 ❩  U+2769 MEDIUM RIGHT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT
 ❫  U+276B MEDIUM FLATTENED RIGHT PARENTHESIS ORNAMENT
 ❭  U+276D MEDIUM RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT
 ❯  U+276F HEAVY RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
 ❱  U+2771 HEAVY RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET ORNAMENT
 ❳  U+2773 LIGHT RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ORNAMENT
 ❵  U+2775 MEDIUM RIGHT CURLY BRACKET ORNAMENT
 ⟆  U+27C6 RIGHT S-SHAPED BAG DELIMITER
 ⟧  U+27E7 MATHEMATICAL RIGHT WHITE SQUARE BRACKET
 ⟩  U+27E9 MATHEMATICAL RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET
 ⟫  U+27EB MATHEMATICAL RIGHT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET
 ⟭  U+27ED MATHEMATICAL RIGHT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
 ⟯  U+27EF MATHEMATICAL RIGHT FLATTENED PARENTHESIS
 ⦄  U+2984 RIGHT WHITE CURLY BRACKET
 ⦆  U+2986 RIGHT WHITE PARENTHESIS
 ⦈  U+2988 Z NOTATION RIGHT IMAGE BRACKET
 ⦊  U+298A Z NOTATION RIGHT BINDING BRACKET
 ⦌  U+298C RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET WITH UNDERBAR
 ⦎  U+298E RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN BOTTOM CORNER
 ⦐  U+2990 RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET WITH TICK IN TOP CORNER
 ⦒  U+2992 RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET WITH DOT
 ⦔  U+2994 RIGHT ARC GREATER-THAN BRACKET
 ⦖  U+2996 DOUBLE RIGHT ARC LESS-THAN BRACKET
 ⦘  U+2998 RIGHT BLACK TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
 ⧙  U+29D9 RIGHT WIGGLY FENCE
 ⧛  U+29DB RIGHT DOUBLE WIGGLY FENCE
 ⧽  U+29FD RIGHT-POINTING CURVED ANGLE BRACKET
 ⸣  U+2E23 TOP RIGHT HALF BRACKET
 ⸥  U+2E25 BOTTOM RIGHT HALF BRACKET
 ⸧  U+2E27 RIGHT SIDEWAYS U BRACKET
 ⸩  U+2E29 RIGHT DOUBLE PARENTHESIS
 〉 U+3009 RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET
 》 U+300B RIGHT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET
 」 U+300D RIGHT CORNER BRACKET
 』 U+300F RIGHT WHITE CORNER BRACKET
 】 U+3011 RIGHT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET
 〕 U+3015 RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
 〗 U+3017 RIGHT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET
 〙 U+3019 RIGHT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
 〛 U+301B RIGHT WHITE SQUARE BRACKET
 〞 U+301E DOUBLE PRIME QUOTATION MARK
 〟 U+301F LOW DOUBLE PRIME QUOTATION MARK
 ﴾  U+FD3E ORNATE LEFT PARENTHESIS
 ︘ U+FE18 PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET
 ︶ U+FE36 PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT PARENTHESIS
 ︸ U+FE38 PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
 ︺ U+FE3A PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
 ︼ U+FE3C PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET
 ︾ U+FE3E PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET
 ﹀ U+FE40 PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET
 ﹂ U+FE42 PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT CORNER BRACKET
 ﹄ U+FE44 PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT WHITE CORNER BRACKET
 ﹈ U+FE48 PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET
 ﹚ U+FE5A SMALL RIGHT PARENTHESIS
 ﹜ U+FE5C SMALL RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
 ﹞ U+FE5E SMALL RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET
 ） U+FF09 FULLWIDTH RIGHT PARENTHESIS
 ］ U+FF3D FULLWIDTH RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET
 ｝ U+FF5D FULLWIDTH RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
 ｠ U+FF60 FULLWIDTH RIGHT WHITE PARENTHESIS
 ｣  U+FF63 HALFWIDTH RIGHT CORNER BRACKET
```

After installing `unichars` with `cpan Unicode::Tussle`, in python:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> cmd = "unichars '\p{Open_Punctuation}' | cut -f2 -d' ' | tr -d '\n'"
>>> open_punct = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode('utf8')
Smartmatch is experimental at /usr/local/bin/unichars line 546.
>>> print (open_punct)
([{༺༼᚛‚„⁅⁽₍〈❨❪❬❮❰❲❴⟅⟦⟨⟪⟬⟮⦃⦅⦇⦉⦋⦍⦏⦑⦓⦕⦗⧘⧚⧼⸢⸤⸦⸨〈《「『【〔〖〘〚〝﴾︗︵︷︹︻︽︿﹁﹃﹇﹙﹛﹝（［｛｟｢
```

Comment: Cool, i didn't know about that `unichars` tool. How could I install that on debian? My question is more of how to port the `\p{Open_Punctuation}` and  `\p{Close_Punctuation}` to python but I guessing knowing what's the punctuations in the set would be a first step.

Comment: Do you want me to delete my answer?

Comment: Nope I think that's fine. But a nice regex to replace them and pad with space like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037626/padding-multiple-character-with-space-python should suffice.

Comment: I don't know python.

Comment: no worries, i'll edit your answers in a while once the installation finishes and I can access the full list of chars =)