# Replacing unicode brackets in python

Tags: python, regex, unicode, punctuation

**How to pad unicode brackets with spaces?**

When i tried to use `re.sub`, I get a `sre_constants.error`:

```
>>> import re
>>> open_punct = ur'([{༺༼᚛‚„⁅⁽₍〈❨❪❬❮❰❲❴⟅⟦⟨⟪⟬⟮⦃⦅⦇⦉⦋⦍⦏⦑⦓⦕⦗⧘⧚⧼⸢⸤⸦⸨〈《「『【〔〖〘〚〝﴾︗︵︷︹︻︽︿﹁﹃﹇﹙﹛﹝（［｛｟｢'
>>> text = u'this is a weird ❴sentence ⟅with some crazy ⟦punctuations sprinkled⟨'
>>> re.sub(open_punct, ur'\1 ', text)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 155, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unexpected end of regular expression
```

**Why did that happen? Why is it that there's an unexpected end of regular expression?**

When i tried to use the `re.escape`, it doesn't raise and error but `re.sub` didn't pad the punctuation with space:

```
>>> re.sub(re.escape(open_punct), ur'\1 ', text)
u'this is a weird \u2774sentence \u27c5with some crazy \u27e6punctuations sprinkled\u27e8'
>>> print re.sub(re.escape(open_punct), ur'\1 ', text)
this is a weird ❴sentence ⟅with some crazy ⟦punctuations sprinkled⟨
```

I could do this but I would expect a regex solution should be more optimal than the loop:

```
>>> for p in open_punct:
...     text = text.replace(p, p+' ')
... 
>>> text
u'this is a weird \u2774 sentence \u27c5 with some crazy \u27e6 punctuations sprinkled\u27e8 '
>>> print text
this is a weird ❴ sentence ⟅ with some crazy ⟦ punctuations sprinkled⟨ 
>>> open_punct
u'([{\u0f3a\u0f3c\u169b\u201a\u201e\u2045\u207d\u208d\u2329\u2768\u276a\u276c\u276e\u2770\u2772\u2774\u27c5\u27e6\u27e8\u27ea\u27ec\u27ee\u2983\u2985\u2987\u2989\u298b\u298d\u298f\u2991\u2993\u2995\u2997\u29d8\u29da\u29fc\u2e22\u2e24\u2e26\u2e28\u3008\u300a\u300c\u300e\u3010\u3014\u3016\u3018\u301a\u301d\ufd3e\ufe17\ufe35\ufe37\ufe39\ufe3b\ufe3d\ufe3f\ufe41\ufe43\ufe47\ufe59\ufe5b\ufe5d\uff08\uff3b\uff5b\uff5f\uff62'
>>> print open_punct
([{༺༼᚛‚„⁅⁽₍〈❨❪❬❮❰❲❴⟅⟦⟨⟪⟬⟮⦃⦅⦇⦉⦋⦍⦏⦑⦓⦕⦗⧘⧚⧼⸢⸤⸦⸨〈《「『【〔〖〘〚〝﴾︗︵︷︹︻︽︿﹁﹃﹇﹙﹛﹝（［｛｟｢
```

Related questions:

- [Padding multiple character with space - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037626/padding-multiple-character-with-space-python)
- [What is the equivalence of perluniprops in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040905/what-is-the-equivalence-of-perluniprops-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[` and `(` have special meaning in a regular expression, the parser is looking for their `]` and `)` counterparts.

If you meant for `open_punct` to be a *character group*, you'd enclose the all characters with `[..]` anyway, at which point both the `(` and `[` can be included unescaped. Your 'expression' matches only text with *all those characters in that order* present.

Since you also expect to reference a capturing group (`\1`), add paretheses:

```
>>> re.sub(u'([{}])'.format(open_punct), ur'\1 ', text)
u'this is a weird \u2774 sentence \u27c5 with some crazy \u27e6 punctuations sprinkled\u27e8 '
>>> print re.sub(u'([{}])'.format(open_punct), ur'\1 ', text)
this is a weird ❴ sentence ⟅ with some crazy ⟦ punctuations sprinkled⟨
```

Note that using `re.escape()` is still a good idea, in case you have a `-` or `]` character, or a `\[group]` sequence in the group you want to match with. `-` defines a sequence of characters (`0-9` for all digits), `]` the end of the group, and `\d`, `\w`, `\s`, etc, all define pre-defined character groups:

```
re.sub(u'([{}])'.format(re.escape(open_punct)), ur'\1 ', text)
```

Comment: Why are the curly brackets needed in `([{}])`?

Comment: @alvas: they are a `str.format()` placeholder. The value of `open_punct` is placed in the string at that location, forming the string `u'([[([{༺༼᚛‚„⁅⁽₍〈❨❪❬❮❰❲❴⟅⟦⟨⟪⟬⟮⦃⦅⦇⦉⦋⦍⦏⦑⦓⦕⦗⧘⧚⧼⸢⸤⸦⸨〈《「『【〔〖〘〚〝﴾︗︵︷︹︻︽︿﹁﹃﹇﹙﹛﹝（［｛｟｢])'`‎

Comment: Oh, i'm blind... I thought i saw the regex. hahahaa.. Thanks Martijn!